# Geometric Algebra : Intersection of Two Planes in R4

Tags: geometric-algebras

I'm working in a four dimensional Euclidean space.  I have two planes, each represented by a bivector.  How do I find the intersection of these two planes? This will be either 0, a vector, or a bivector.

I could do this if I could find the smallest subspace that contains both planes.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your $2$-vectors are $a\wedge b$ and $c\wedge d$, with $a,b,c,d$ column vectors. Consider the matrix

$$ M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 | & | & | & | \\
 a & b & c & d \\
 | & | & | & | 
\end{bmatrix}. $$

Note $\{a,b\}$ and $\{c,d\}$ are linearly independent. If the column rank of $M$ is $2$, then $\mathrm{span}\{a,b\}=\mathrm{span}\{c,d\}$ are the same plane. If the column rank of $M$ is $3$, then we can compute a $u$ in its kernel, unique up to scalar multiples, and then we can say that $u_1a+u_2b=-u_3c-u_4d$ is in the intersection of these planes. And if the column rank of $M$ is $4$ then the planes do not intersect.